# Android Studio setAdapter not recognized

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm doing an exercise in ch7 of Android Boot Camp for Developers 2nd ed. The book aims at ICS but I've attempted to not use the deprecated **Gallery** widget and use **HorizontalScrollView** instead.

Now **setAdapter** isn't recognized and further in the code I have an issue with **arg0** and **arg2** not being recognized either. I can make the **setAdapter** issue go away by reverting calls to **HorizontalScrollView** back to **Gallery** but the **arg** issues still remain. Below is the entire code of the smallish class file.

**Thank you!**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public Integer[] Animals = {R.drawable.elephant, R.drawable.gorilla, R.drawable.leopard, R.drawable.monkey, R.drawable.panda, R.drawable.redpanda};

    ImageView imageView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        HorizontalScrollView ga = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgAnimal);
        ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        ga.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected picture " + (arg2 + 1)
                        + " of the endangered species", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imageView.setImageResource(Animals[arg2]);

            }
        });


    }


    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Animals.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView pic = new ImageView(context);
            pic.setImageResource(Animals[arg0]);
            pic.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            pic.setLayoutParams(new HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams(200, 175));
            return pic;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you declare these two variables?
btw, the use of these two variables is position of array Animals...

Comment: I declared Animals right after the opening "public class MainActivity extends Activity {"

Answer (score 0):

replace these two variables to `position`

Comment: you mean arg and arg2? OKay done that. The red went away from them but now the entire 'public void onItemClick method is red squigglied (is there a proper term for this?) Mouse over says "setOnClickListener (android.view.View.OnClickListener) in View cannot be applied to [these are in red now] (anonymous android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) Also setAdapter is still red along with several of the R's

Comment: should use View.OnClickListener in setOnClickListener not AdapterView.OnItemClickListener. HorizontalScrollView is not AdapterView, it doesn't have setOnItemClickListener and setAdapter methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap a `LinearLayout` or something like this with `HorizontalScrollView`, exactly the same way you do this with the regular `ScrollView`. Other (better) option is to use a `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager`, adjusting it to scroll horizontally. Something like this:

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

In this case, you will need to make your adapter extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

Comment: I don't see why changing that would help the java. Can you explain? I have the horizontal scroll view wrapped with a linear layout but that doesn't change any of the red R's or code in the java class./